# Why don't you need a getchar() while getting integer as an input?

Tags: c

```
int main()
{
   char a,b;
   scanf("%c",&a);
   getchar();
   scanf ("%c",&b);
}
```

If you don't use getchar for character scanf takes the whitespace as an input but for integer you don't need getchar:

```
int main()
{
   int a,b;
   scanf("%d",&a);
   scanf ("%d",&b);
}
```

Comment: Is there a question here?

Comment: On what basis `scanf` will decide whitespace is not intended character entered by user? For number it knows that whitespace is not a number and it skips.

Comment: `scanf` is a very smart function. It skips the whitespaces when you try to read a number.

Comment: You don't need a `getchar` in the first case and it will break things. If you type "ab<enter>" into that code, it will read the "a", ignore the "b" and then read the enter as the second character and store it in `b`! That can't possibly be right.

Answer (score 1):

> Why don't you need a getchar() while getting integer as an input?

Interpreting your question in terms of the differences between the two provided examples, you seem to be asking about the difference between `scanf`'s processing of `%c` directives and its processing of `%d` directives.  At its simplest, the explanation is that `scanf`'s specifications say that when it attempts to match a `%d` directive, it must skip any leading whitespace.  Which, by the way, may comprise any number of characters, and which recognizes more characters than just ASCII 0x20 as whitespace.

The `%c` is actually the oddball here.  Of all the `scanf` directives that match and convert input, it is one of only two that *don't* skip leading whitespace.  This makes sense, because it allows `scanf()` to read space characters as input, and because you can instruct it to match (and therefore skip) leading whitespace by inserting a space character into the format string immediately before a `%c` (or any other) directive.  Or you can read and ignore *any* single character, as your `getchar()` actually does, by inserting an additional `%*c` directive into the format.

The whitespace skipping performed for most other directives is a convenience catering to fixed-format tabular data, which may have varying amounts of space between individual items.

Comment: tl;dr: %c does not skip whitespace while other conversion specifiers do.

Comment: `%[...]` likewise does not consume leading whitespace.

Comment: Yes, @DavidC.Rankin, that's the other of the two that don't.  This answer alludes to it, but did not name it explicitly.

Comment: Is enter also a white-space character?

Comment: @CyborgGamer, enter is a key on the keyboard, not a character.  But typing it ordinarily causes a newline character (`'\n'`) to be sent, and yes, that is a whitespace character.

Comment: What are whitespaces. Is '\0' also a whitespace?

Comment: @CyborgGamer, for the purposes of `scanf()`, whitespace characters are those for which the [`isspace()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/isalpha.3.html) function returns a nonzero value.  These are locale-dependent, but in the default locale they are space, carriage return (`'\r'`), newline (`'\n'`), form feed (`'\f'`), horizontal tab (`'\t'`), and vertical tab (`'\v'`).  The null character, `'\0'`, is not counted as whitespace in any locale I know, but if your data may contain null characters then *formatted* I/O functions such as `scanf` may not be the best choice.

Answer (score 0):

> Why don't you need a getchar() while getting integer as an input?

`"%d"` skips leading white-space - including the left-over <kbd>enter</kbd> of the prior `scanf("%c",&a);`.
  `"%c"` does not.

> Input white-space characters (as specified by the `isspace` function) are skipped, unless
>   the specification includes a `[`, `c`, or `n` specifier.
>   C11dr §7.21.6.2 8